# Show lightbox for images of individual chat message Jquery (and php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a chat stream with laravel. My question probably isn't laravel related as much as jquery-ish. So I have the user store multiple images in a single data field in mysql. I then do json_decode and display the image:

```
@foreach($messages as $message)
 {{$message->content}} <br>
 @for($i = 0; $i < count(json_decode($message->images)); $i++)
    <img src="{{Storage::url(json_decode($message->images)[$i])}}" style="max-width: 50px" onclick="openModal(this), currentSlide({{$i.','. $message->id}})" class="hover-shadow slides{{$message->id}}" />
 @endfor
@endforeach
```

This gives me a layout as follows:[image]

So that is working fine. My issue is that I want to click on an image and open a modal light box. I've tried to use the code on w3schools at [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp) but i'm running into trouble. I don't know how to get the images from that specific chat message and transfer just those to the light box. 
This is the javascript I've got now, obviously it isn't working.

```
function currentSlide(n, o) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n, o);
}

function showSlides(n, o) {

  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides"+o);
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
        $('#modal-content').append('
            <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="'+$(slides[i]).attr('src')+'" style="width:100%">
            </div>');
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Can someone help me get my images to display from the individual chat message in a light box that I can scroll through? Just for reference, i had to alter the html on that example link to look like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="modal-content">

            </div>

<!-- Next/previous controls -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My thoughts were that I could append a new DOM element to the #modal-content div for each image that went through the loop.

This is the page source output of a chat item:

```
<p class="left clearfix">
    <span class="chat-img1 pull-left">
     <img src="/storage/IzUXSgXNlj0CM0MEEXl1U0rYtED0iMR9y1RdZ5cI.jpeg" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" style="width:50px; float:left">
    </span>
<div class="chat-body1 clearfix">
 <p>test with photos <br />
    <div class="imggrp41">
     <img src="/storage/post-images/Dl6FTni406BfzPKSnshxytfrqEzcSb6m4ABdvqaE.jpeg" style="max-width: 50px" onclick="openModal(this), currentSlide(0,41)" class="hover-shadow slides41" />
    </div>
 </p>
<div class="chat_time pull-right" style="float: right;">7 minutes ago</div>
</div>
</p>
```

Comment: I suppose each message is inside its own container. Something like a div holding the images and text etc. So you should do something like `this.parentNode.children` inside the click event function. That will return you all elements inside your message container. After that it's a simple matter of looping through them while checking if they're an image element or not.

Comment: thanks for the reply @icecub, could you maybe provide me a code example? javascript is not my strongest skill unfortunately.

Comment: Not without a code example of an actual message. Answers to a question are required to _answer_ a question. I can't do that unless I'm sure it'll work in your case. You'll have to edit your question with an example of the html output for a single message.

Comment: the content of the first code block in my question isn't what you're talking about? it has my two foreach loops that display the message contents (text and images)

Comment: No. Just go on your chat. Post a message. Right click -> Inspect element. Make sure you copy the entire message part, not just the single element it'll show and put that in your question. That's all

Comment: ok. i did that and added it to the question

Comment: Oof.. That's going to cause you a lot more issues than just the images. Putting divs and images inside p elements is invalid html. Not to mention that it seems that you're reloading the entire chat history on each new message? Unless this isn't a live chat system. Also, if you post 2 or more images in a single message, are they each contained in their own div like `<div class="imggrp41">` is used for the image here? Or will they all be in the same one?

Comment: i'm not loading the entire history on each message and yes this is a live system. essentially what i'm doing is building the html as a php response on the back end and then when the message gets through the system, the javascript just appends the already built html to the bottom of the chat box. And yes, they are currently each contained in their own div. The '41' in the 'imggrp41' is the message id in the database that those images are associated with. i figured that would let me grab each image in that class. But then i just assigned in in 'slides41' on the image element itself.

Comment: Well as I said, your html output is invalid. That makes it impossible to properly retrieve the images inside a message as you can see here: [https://jsfiddle.net/k0d6c9rf](https://jsfiddle.net/k0d6c9rf) Should you be able to fix that mistake, then this example will work [https://jsfiddle.net/k0d6c9rf/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/k0d6c9rf/1/)

Comment: ok thanks so much for taking your time to help me. i'll study those fiddles and see if i can implement it

Comment: I would however highly recommend that you use a websocket instead. It'll be a LOT faster and way more light weight than any form of long or short polling techniques. Since you like PHP, [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) would be the perfect library for you. Their tutorial is even to setup a basic chatsystem

Comment: i'm using pusher. it's already going through web sockets.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes here in the future, this plugin worked wonders for me: [lightbox by Lokesh Dhakar](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). It's super simple and all you have to do is apply the same "data-lightbox" attribute to every image that you want linked in the same lightbox series. So after following the html-correcting advice of @icecub in the comments, this is my final code:

```
@if($message->images != null)
 <div>
  @for($i = 0; $i < count(json_decode($message->images)); $i++)
   <a href = "{{Storage::url(json_decode($message->images)[$i])}}"   data-lightbox = "message{{$message->id}}" ><img src="{{Storage::url(json_decode($message->images)[$i])}}" style="max-width: 50px; cursor: pointer;" /></a>
  @endfor
 </div>
@endif
```

The data-lightbox attribute is set to the message ID from Laravel and if there's more than one image, it'll get the same image id, thus creating a lightbox specifically with the images from that chat message.